# Rails + AngularJs web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm going to create some AngularJS/Rails app, but I'm a newby in developing with AngularJS. So, I have one question: should I divide my project with 2 parts: the first one is just HTML/CSS/JS code and the second one is Rails API? I also can do all work in the Rails project. What should I prefer? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Personally I like to separate it into two separate parts. I like to have one git repository for the front end and one for the backend

Answer (score 0):

Personally I feel that the clean way is to put the `html` files under the `public` folder. Also this will make it easier to point Angular routes to your `html` files as you don't have to mix `.erb` with your `javascript`, which also gives you the ability to use pure `coffeescript` everywhere (You cannot make `.coffee.erb` files sadly).

The folder structure for all my Angular applications was following:

**Angular coffee files:**

```
app/assets/javascripts/angular/
```

In there I have seperate folders for controllers services and directives. In controllers folder I have the same namespacing going on as in Rails controllers folder.

So if there is a content namespace where I have likes and media controllers inside of it, then it looks the same in Angular folder.

**Angular template files:**

```
public/templates/
```

In `public/templates` where I keep the `.html` files, I follow the rails way of naming folders and files, and also keep the namespacing. So if users folder has an index page and a show page then I also have `show.html` and `index.html`.

Here are some very good examples where people have made Angular - Rails applications:

[CafeTownsend](https://github.com/sectore/CafeTownsend-Angular-Rails)

[Rails4-AngularJs example](https://github.com/mkwiatkowski/todo-rails4-angularjs)